# Setting time in Citrus TestSuite.xml/junitreports

Tags: java, spring, citrus-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to capture the time elapsed for the entire testsuite and individual test cases.

I've noticed that when `/junitreports/TEST-*.xml` and `TEST-TestSuite.xml` is generated after I run a `JUnit` or `TestNG` test case, the time element is not being populated in both `<testsuite>` and `<testcase>` as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="TestSuite" time="0.0" tests="3" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
    <testcase name="Read1Test" classname="com.consol.citrus.tests.ReadTest" time="0.0"/>
    <testcase name="Read2Test" classname="com.consol.citrus.tests.ReadTest" time="0.0"/>
    <testcase name="Read3Test" classname="com.consol.citrus.tests.ReadTest" time="0.0"/>
</testsuite>
```

I've had a look in `citrus-core` `JUnitReporter.java` and `test.duration` is initialised, but is not part of the `TestResult` object or any of the parameters inside `createReportContent()` method.

I'm just wondering if there is still a way to inject a time elapsed in testsuite and testcase?